# Python function to convert camelCase to Sentence Case

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to convert my camelCaseSentence to Sentence Case.

Example:

> ***String: 'sarimChaudharyIsMyName'***

So the output of this should be...

> ***String: 'Sarim Chaudhary Is My Name'***

Comment: Looks like title case to me

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple regex approach using the help of the `title()` function:

```py
inp = 'sarimChaudharyIsMyName'
output = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', inp).title()
print(output)  # Sarim Chaudhary Is My Name
```

We can maybe improve performance a bit by avoiding the `title()` call and instead just uppercasing the first character:

```py
inp = 'sarimChaudharyIsMyName'
output = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', inp)
output = output[0].upper() + output[1:]
print(output)  # Sarim Chaudhary Is My Name
```

Comment: In terms of efficiency, calling `title` after `sub` requires to read the whole string again. I imagine that handling the case of the first character separately should be better.

Comment: @mozway Good point, and I have added your version as well.

Comment: A few tests indicate that `title` takes about 10% of the time, your second version is ~10% faster. Not necessarily important to optimize in all cases but better be aware ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def camel_to_Sentence_Case(a):
    temp = a[0].upper()
    for i in a[1:]:
        if i.isupper():
            temp+= ' '+i
        else:
            temp+=i
    
    return temp
```